# Rasterio & rioxarray no longer compatible with fairly standard modules

Tags: python, rasterio, anaconda, conda, cartopy

I just bought a new computer and want to read a geotiff and plot it in cartopy. I'm typing:

```
conda create --name my_env

conda activate my_env

conda install numpy pandas jupyter cartopy xarray matplotlib netCDF4 tqdm scipy rioxarray
```

This combination of libraries seemingly can't be solved. It also can't be solved if you change rioxarray to rasterio. If I remove that library things work fine.

Is this combination of libraries too much to ask?

Answer (score 1):

that combo of packages does not seem like too much to ask! Two things you might try here:

1.) Use `miniconda` rather than `conda` - this version ships with no pre-installed packages, but otherwise functions exactly like `conda`. This will reduce the size of your environment and the chance that packages will conflict.

2.) Try using the `conda-forge` channel for package distribution.

`conda config --add channels conda-forge`

`conda config --set channel_priority strict`

And then proceed with your `conda install...` as you normally would.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend that you have a look at [miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge)! It comes with `conda` and `mamba` pre-configured to use `conda-forge` as a default channel.

Then, instead of using `conda install...` use `mamba install ...` and prepare to be amazed by the blazing speed at which `mamba` will solve and install your dependencies ;-)